# ¿Como guardar grandes cantidades de información evitando datos repetitivos?

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, sqlite, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos

¡Buenas!, tengo un problema y quisiera saber si mi solución es óptima o viable.

Les comento el contexto del problema:
Se requiere tener un registro de los productos y su información inherente (como precio, stock, fecha en la que obtuve la información del producto, entre otras cosas) extraída de diferentes sitios webs. Este registro al ser diario, genera un gran volumen de datos.

**El problema es que estoy acumulando muchos datos repititivos y no estoy seguro como evitar esto**

Mi solución pensada:
Todos los días se chekean estos productos por lo tanto lo primero es:

1. Guardar por lo menos una vez la información de los productos.
2. Si no cambió, guardo un registro con la fecha y el id del producto inmediatamente anterior, de esta forma evito tener información duplicada en la base de datos.
3. Si cambió en algunos sus campos, guardo un registro completo de éste producto en la base de datos.

¿Quisiera saber si existe otra forma de encarar este tipo de problemas?.

**PD: el motor actual es Sqlite3. ¿Sería recomendable migrar a MongoDB o a alguna otra base de dato no SQL?**

*Desde ya muchas gracias.*

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta tal como está formulada se basa en opiniones, lo cual ocasionará su cierre. En cuanto a tu duda, IMHO, dependerá de las capacidades de servidor de base de datos para almacenar lo que tú consideras un gran *volumen* de datos. Has colocado 2 etiquetas totalmente antagónicas: [tag:mongodb] y [tag:sqlite]. ¿Con cuál motor estás trabajando? Saludos

Comment: empieza por definir gran volumen de datos... sigue explicando correctamente que base de datos vas a usar... luego explica que te beneficia guardar un par de datos menos por dia... luego explica para que queres guardar datos que son exactamente iguales en lugar de guardar rangos de datos... en fin... explicate mejor y tal vez la pregunta no sea basada en opiniones...

Comment: !Hola @MauricioContreras muchas gracias por comentar!

Comment: ¡Hola @gbianchi muchas gracias por comentar! Bien me explico mejor. Es necesario tener el histórico de estos datos para luego poder analizarlos, lo que trae como consecuencia un volumen de datos actual de aproximadamente 5 millones que se acrecientan por día en 88295 registros. Me procupa el hecho de que posiblemente esté siendo redundante con la información que almaceno, ya que tal como está ahora el sistema, guarda todos los datos todos los días.

Comment: @gbianchi con respecto a lo de **guardar rango de datos**, ¿podrías ser más especifico por favor? no entiendo muy bien a lo que te refieres !muchas gracias!.

Comment: 5 millones en sqlite parece imposible.. en mongodb (que no es una base relacional) es otro cantar distinto... primero por favor, clarifica la pregunta a ver si deja de ser basada en opiniones, para que podamos ayudarte... los historicos de datos siempre ocupan mucho espacio y no suelen guardarse con los datos que uno procesa comunmente... se guardan en bases historicas...

Comment: @gbianchi Genial tu comentario sobre las bases historicas, aberiguaré más sobre el tema. Con respecto a la  pregunta, espero que ahora esté más clara. ¡Gracias!

Comment: una base no tiene nada que ver con la otra, y las bases no relacionales no tienen nada que ver con la relacionales y se usan para cosas muy distintas... esta pregunta sigue siendo basada en opiniones... y es un tema muy largo siquiera para ponerlo en una respuesta. Sqlite no esta preparado para esto que planteas ni de casualidad...